# Other output from classification result by package tree needed

Tags: r, function, tree, classification

The output from tree classification by package `tree` of a class target field with several class values looks like this:

```
      30-39     40-49     50-59     60plus       to29
1 0.1723497 0.2145071 0.5151891 0.02588345 0.07207068
2 0.1451786 0.1370050 0.2740099 0.32061886 0.12318770
4 0.1723497 0.2145071 0.5151891 0.02588345 0.07207068
```

But I want the result to be in the way:

```
1  50-59
2  60plus
4  50-59
```

Are there any implemented functions (I have not found any) that will provide this output automatically or do I have to write an R function?

This function has to fetch the max value of each line, get the index of the matched value in this line and then provide the age class of this index, like `60plus`.

Comment: ok your edit changes things...where do the `**` come fro  are they in the data? and only around random data pints in different columns?

Comment: hi, I used the "**" only for formatting reasons in order to sign the max value of each line. I thought, this would make the font bold... Please ignore them. Stefan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `predict` function there is a parameter called `type`. It defines the type of output you want for the prediction.

Just do

```
predict(treeobject, type="class")
```

And you will get the class of higher probability.

See the [reference manual](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tree/tree.pdf) for further informations. (predict.tree function)

Comment: hi João Daniel, thank you very much! That was all I needed! If it would be only always as easy as this... ;-) regards, Stefan